# How can I compare 2 Jenkin slave nodes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops

We have 8 nodes and our tests are getting executed on a particular node and all the other nodes we are not able to find the .sh file

is there any way we can compare our 2 Jenkin nodes(one where the file is executing and others where it is not) and figure out what is missing on other nodes?

Comment: Did you setup the nodes manually or per infrastructure as code (terraform, ansible, puppet etc..)? If you did it manually I guess it will be hard to compare the directly.

Comment: We set it up manually

@Schaeffler can you guide me what is the best way I can resolve my issue.

Comment: My first guess is the .sh script is simply missing on this specific node. Everything else is quite hard to debug with the information you provided.